# I am receiving a conflict between void main() and using namespace std;? I am using codeblocks

Tags: c++

The code is as follows:
It is working fine with int main(), but using void main is giving an error.
Kindly help out. Thanks in advance.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
void main() //I am getting error at void main
{

    int a,b,c;
    printf("enter two no.");
    scanf("%d",);
    c=a*b;
    cout<<"result is"<<c;
    getch();

}
```

Comment: This is what happens when you learn C++ using a compiler that's 20+ years old.

Comment: What is the error that `void main()` is giving?

Answer (score 2):

As per ANSI and ISO standards, main function must have int return type. void main is not allowed.